# Swiper autoplay stops if you switch tabs or minimize the browser

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, swiper.js

I made an autoplay progress for the swiper using CSS. When an active class is added to the pagination, I run a css animation that lasts as long as the swiper autoplay delay. Everything works fine if you don't switch browser tabs or if you don't minimize the browser. As soon as we switch tabs the swiper autoplay will pause and cause the animation to stop. Maybe someone knows how you can affect it?

```
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay } from 'swiper';

const heroSwiper = new Swiper('.hero__swiper', {
  modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay],
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5000,
    waitForTransition: false,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  slidesPerView: 1,
  speed: 800,
  grabCursor: true,
  navigation: {
    prevEl: '.hero__navigation-button--prev',
    nextEl: '.hero__navigation-button--next',
  },
  pagination: {
    clickable: true,
    el: '.hero__swiper-pagination',
    renderBullet: (i, className) => {
      return `<button class="${className}">${(`0${i + 1}`).slice(-2)}</button>`;
    },
    type: 'bullets',
  },
});
```

```
  &__swiper-pagination {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 12px !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    display: inline-flex !important;
    width: auto !important;
    transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;

    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-flex;
      width: auto !important;
      height: auto !important;
      margin: 0 24px 0 0 !important;
      color: #605647;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 20px;
      background: none !important;
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      transition: 0.8s !important;
      pointer-events: all;

      &::before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 35px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 1px;
        background: rgba(#fff, 0.3);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.8s;
        content: "";
      }

      &::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 35px;
        width: 0;
        height: 1px;
        background: rgba(#fff, 1);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.8s;
        content: "";
      }

      &.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
        margin-right: 110px !important;
        color: #fff;

        &:last-child {
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }

        &::before {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 1;
        }

        &::after {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 1;
          animation: pagination-progress 5s linear;
        }
      }

      &:last-child {
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
    }
  }


@keyframes pagination-progress {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }

  100% {
    width: 75px;
  }
}
```

**UPD**
**The solution to the problem:**

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    /* Since swiper is still running in the background and only restarts 
    the animation when the user returns to the tab, it was decided to delete the class. */
    if (document.querySelector('.swiper-pagination-bullet-active')) {
      document.querySelector('.swiper-pagination-bullet-active').classList.remove('swiper-pagination-bullet-active');
    }

    // Without timeout the css animation does not start
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-pagination-bullet')[heroSwiper.activeIndex].classList.add('swiper-pagination-bullet-active');
    }, 10);
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.swiper-pagination-bullet-active').classList.remove('swiper-pagination-bullet-active');
  }
});
```

Thanks Xena Lysenkova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Swiper slider pauses autoplay after switching between browser tabs.
And it restarts showing the current slide again when you return back.
Try to restart the progress animation when a tab with your slider has become visible.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
        // restart animate progress
    } else {
       // stop animate progress
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!!! Now I just remove the `.swiper-pagination-bullet-active' class after switching tabs, and when I go back to that tab, the CSS animation starts again.

Comment: I noticed one peculiarity of swiper. If you switch a tab and observe the active pagination class through devtools, the class switches as if the tab is open, that is, swiper does not pause. Swiper starts autoplay again only when you return to the tab.